# Order of execution of print with pthreads in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, mutex

I'm using C and I want to get the String "ABCABCABCABCABCABC" in the output screen through multithreading. One thread displays the 'A' character, the second one displays the 'B' and the third one displays the 'C'. If I compile the following code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define cantidad_impresion_letra 6
pthread_mutex_t semaforo = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *escribirA(void *unused){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidad_impresion_letra;i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&semaforo);
        printf("A");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&semaforo);
    }
}

void *escribirB(void *unused){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidad_impresion_letra;i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&semaforo);
        printf("B");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&semaforo);
    }
}

void *escribirC(void *unused){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidad_impresion_letra;i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&semaforo);
        printf("C");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&semaforo);
    }
}

int main(){
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;
    
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,escribirA,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,escribirB,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3,NULL,escribirC,NULL);
        
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    
    return(0);
}
```

On Windows through Dev-C++, the console throws me: `ABACBACBACBACBACBC` but if I compile **the same** code in Linux, I get `CCCCCCBBBBBBAAAAAA`.
Can someone explain me this please?

Comment: With multi-threading, generally speaking you *want* the threads to work independently and in parallel. If you want a specific order, then *don't* use threads, because then you would be wasting resources.

Comment: If you must do this pointless exercise, note that you only need one thread function.  Pass an index as the pthread_create argument.  Use three condvars or semaphores so that each thread can signal the next along the chain.  The global counter/poll solution is hopele...'non - optimal' and get a lower mark.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain me this please?

The different output in linux has to do with the used scheduler.

[man sched](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html)

> Since Linux 2.6.23, the default scheduler is CFS, the "Completely Fair Scheduler".

[Completely Fair Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler):

> Each per-CPU run-queue of type cfs_rq **sorts** sched_entity structures in a **time-ordered** fashion into a red-black tree (or 'rbtree' in Linux lingo), where the leftmost node is occupied by the entity that has received the **least** slice of **execution time** (which is saved in the vruntime field of the entity). The nodes are indexed by processor "execution time" in nanoseconds.

**What does that mean:**

Each thread runs so fast, that the scheduler doesn't deem it necessary to perform a context switch.

There are only 6 iteration steps and an output into a buffered stream (no newline, therefore no output to the terminal until a flush occurs).

Do the test, increase the iteration steps, add more characters to the output and add a newline character (`\n`).

The sequence will start to change.

On my system, the sequence started to change with 200 iteration steps and 3 characters (plus `\n`).

---

> I'm using C and I want to get the String "ABCABCABCABCABCABC"

**1. Sequential output is best achieved through sequential execution.**

- use only one thread (single threaded)

**2. Notify/Wait**

- each thread performs an iteration, signals the other thread and then waits for a signal to arrive in order to continue on the next cycle

**3. Barrier**

```
//introduce NUM_THREAD lists
char dataA[cantidad_impresion_letra];
char dataB[cantidad_impresion_letra];
char dataC[cantidad_impresion_letra];

//let the thread do their work without any disturbance
void *escribirA(void *unused){ //unused could be used to pass the lists
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidad_impresion_letra;i++){
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&semaforo); //not needed
        //instead of printf("A");
        dataA[i] = 'A';
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&semaforo); //not needed
    }
}

//same for escribirB but write into dataB
//same for escribirC but write into dataC

int main()
{
    //...
    //after joining the threads
    //collective output in any desired order
    for (int i=0; i < cantidad_impresion_letra; ++i) {
        printf("%c", dataA[i]);
        printf("%c", dataB[i]);
        printf("%c", dataC[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The advantages:

- no lock/unlock (if the global lists are not accessed otherwise)
- no waiting and broadcasting
- guaranteed synchronized output
- let the OS decide when it is best to yield a thread (scheduler)

Disadvantage:

- more memory intensive (depends on the number of threads and the iteration steps)

Comment: The references about the scheduling are interesting for sure but I guess that the OP wanted a portable solution (at least on both Linux and Windows) to serialize the thread execution. And it is possible to make it with user space pthread API even if this is unusual to serialize threads in a multi-threaded environment (as you said).

Comment: @RachidK. Agreed, but the OP also asked for an explanation and i've tried to give one (that it is an os thing). The user Cheatah in the comments above, gave a reason not to use parallelism and the user Rachid K. presented a solution on how the desired output could be realized. So, i think there is now enough information, that the OP is able to rethink the implementation (if the increasing cost is worth it).

Comment: I agree with you: this is finally a complementary information.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the order of execution in a global volatile variable named for example *order* which is set with the values 0, 1 and 2 circularly (thanks to an incrementation and a modulo operation). This variable is checked with a condition variable:

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int order = 0;

#define cantidad_impresion_letra 6
pthread_mutex_t semaforo = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


void *escribirA(void *unused){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidad_impresion_letra;i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&semaforo);
        while (order != 0) {
          // Wake up another thread before going to sleep
          pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
          pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &semaforo);
        }
        printf("A");
        order = (order + 1) % 3;
        fflush(stdout);
        // Wake up another thread
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&semaforo);
    }
}

void *escribirB(void *unused){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidad_impresion_letra;i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&semaforo);
        while (order != 1) {
          // Wake up another thread before going to sleep
          pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
          pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &semaforo);
        }
        printf("B");
        order = (order + 1) % 3;
        fflush(stdout);
        // Wake up another thread
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&semaforo);
    }
}

void *escribirC(void *unused){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidad_impresion_letra;i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&semaforo);
        while (order != 2) {
          // Wake up another thread before going to sleep
          pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
          pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &semaforo);
        }
        printf("C");
        order = (order + 1) % 3;
        fflush(stdout);
        // Wake up another thread
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&semaforo);
    }
}

int main(){
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;
    
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,escribirA,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,escribirB,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3,NULL,escribirC,NULL);
        
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);
    
    return(0);
}
```

Example of execution:

```
$ gcc order.c -o order -lpthread
$ ./order
ABCABCABCABCABCABC
```

Answer (score 0):

> On Windows through Dev-C++, the console throws me: ABACBACBACBACBACBC but if I compile the same code in Linux, I get CCCCCCBBBBBBAAAAAA.
> Can someone explain me this please?

The Linux behavior is what you should expect. Some thread has to start running first. Whichever thread it is, the other two threads will be blocked. That thread will be able to continue running for some time since there is nothing that it needs to wait for.

The behavior you see in Windows is awful -- the worst possible. Either it's keeping all three threads scheduled or it's not. If it's keeping all three threads scheduled, it's using three cores for work that can be done equally fast with just one core. If it's not keeping all three threads scheduled, then you are getting one context switch per character of output and wasting CPU time constantly populating the code and data caches because you just switched from another task.